# Very Slow Boot with Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: boot, 20.04, services

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from 18.04, the boot time, which wasn't great, is now even worse and takes typically two and a half minutes. I've stopped the `NetworkManager-wait-online` service, but this only makes a small difference.  Having read of similar problems with previous versions I'm none the wiser.

`systemd-analyze` timings are below:

```
Startup finished in 39.960s (kernel) + 1min 46.291s (userspace) = 2min 26.252s graphical.target reached after 1min 45.661s in userspace
```

The main items from `systemd-analyze blame` are:

```
56.025s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                       
27.021s dev-sda1.device                                                  
23.838s snapd.service                                                    
21.920s networkd-dispatcher.service                                      
20.433s systemd-journal-flush.service                                    
18.533s apport-autoreport.service                                        
17.737s accounts-daemon.service                                          
17.062s dev-loop31.device
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` shows:

```
graphical.target @1min 45.661s
└─multi-user.target @1min 45.660s
  **└─snapd.seeded.service @1min 1.081s +663ms**
    **└─snapd.service @37.238s +23.838s**
      └─basic.target @35.464s
        └─sockets.target @35.464s
          **└─snapd.socket @35.462s +1ms**
            └─sysinit.target @35.392s
              └─swap.target @35.391s
                **└─dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap @35.263s +128ms**
                  └─dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device @35.262s**
```

Any help is welcome. The computer is a Sony Vaio laptop, bought in 2012, with an Intel i3 processor.

Comment: Same here. Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I copied the files I wanted to keep then did a clean install from scratch and this worked well. It took a while to get up and running again but the boot time was half what I had previously. I think the 'upgrade' install probably caused the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove snap and install software from normal repositories:

```bsh
sudo apt purge snap*
```